# Try Except: EOFError handling

Tags: python, arcpy, grib

I'm trying to perform an extractsubdataset_management tool in python on a set of GRB files. Part of the syntax for the tool requires me to specify the number of subdatasets as the 3rd parameter. The issue i'm having is handling a different quantity of subdatasets. One GRB file may have 112 subsets while another may have 114. The code I have performs the extraction, but shoots an error when receiving no input if i specify the higher number of subsets...

```
import os
import arcpy

path = "C:/CHRIS/testfolder/testgrib"
gribs = os.listdir(path)
grib = gribs

os.chdir(path)
print os.getcwd()

grb = arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/CHRIS/testfolder/testgrib"

for item in gribs:
    print item
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, item + '.subdata'))
    folder = path + "/" + item + ".subdata"
    for i in range(0,115):
        numb=str(i)
        try:
            arcpy.ExtractSubDataset_management(item, folder + "/test" + numb + ".tif", numb)
        except EOFError:
            break
```

my question is... Is there a better way to handle the EOFError exception than what I am currently using? I'd like for the tool to receive the error, break from the current input and move to the next GRB file... I keep getting an EOFError: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host... If i limit my range to 112, the tool works but it will omit the remaining subsets that i need... For some reason, 'Break' does not do what it should in the context of my script...

Comment: You want to use `continue` instead of `break`.

Comment: I tried continue in lieu of break, and I still receive "exceptions.EOFError: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically count how many gribs you have before going into that loop?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no. I looked for that solution, but came up with nothing on all attempts.